# Native Base Footer Nav Tabs

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am new to React Native and have created a footer with three button tabs. I am now wondering how to render different screens by clicking the buttons. My code:

```
export default class Uptown extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Title>Uptown</Title>
      </Header>

      <Content>
        <App />
      </Content>

            <Footer>
                <FooterTab>
                  <Button>
                    Contact
                  </Button>
                  <Button>
                    Here
                  </Button>
                  <Button>
                    Me
                  </Button>
                </FooterTab>
            </Footer>
        </Container>
  );
 }
}
```

How would I go about changing screens when the buttons are pressed?

Answer (score 9):

You can add conditional rendering instead of static `<App/>` tag. You can use code as following to render conditionally based on selected footer. (I used state variable to store selected page index. When index changed, render function automatically called by engine)

```
import First from './Home' // your first screen
import Next from './Next' // your second screen

class Updown extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {index: 0} // default screen index
   }

   switchScreen(index) {
      this.setState({index: index})
   }

   render() {
      let AppComponent = null;

      if (this.state.index == 0) {
         AppComponent = First
      } else {
         AppComponent = Second
      }

      return (
         <Container>
           <Header><Title> Header... </Title></Header>
           <Content> <AppComponent/> </Content>
           <Footer>
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen(0) }> First </Button>
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen(1) }> Second </Button>
           </Footer>
         </Container>
       )
   }
}
```

Comment: you should use: this.state = {index: 0} in the constructor instead of: this.setState({...})

Comment: @HosseinMobasher . I am able to show the content like this but the problem is that the content from another tab is not scrollable. When I view the tab without rendering from external, it is scrollable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Somename what tab's library are you using?

Comment: @HosseinMobasher thanks mate. I got it sorted. I had defined `content` in both pages. I removed it from the importing tab and its working. Don't know what you mean by tab's library. Please elaborate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53774572/5498065 can you please take a look at this am trying to do same but i couldn't find solution for this

Answer (score 5):

I think as of native-base v2.3.1 (August 2017) the recommended way is to follow [documentation on React Navigation / TabNavigator](http://docs.nativebase.io/docs/examples/navigation/StackNavigationExample.html). Of course this is only if you actually intend to use `TabNavigator` (which I do) with the benefits of React Navigation (I'm not knowledgeable enough to say what those are).

But if you want the footer tabs to be part of the main navigation structure of your app, instead of an ad-hoc mechanism for one page, this seems to be the way to go.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import LucyChat from "./LucyChat.js";
import JadeChat from "./JadeChat.js";
import NineChat from "./NineChat.js";
import { TabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Button, Text, Icon, Footer, FooterTab } from "native-base";
export default (MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator(
  {
    LucyChat: { screen: LucyChat },
    JadeChat: { screen: JadeChat },
    NineChat: { screen: NineChat }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarComponent: props => {
      return (
        <Footer>
          <FooterTab>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 0}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("LucyChat")}>
              <Icon name="bowtie" />
              <Text>Lucy</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 1}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("JadeChat")}>
              <Icon name="briefcase" />
              <Text>Nine</Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              vertical
              active={props.navigationState.index === 2}
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("NineChat")}>
              <Icon name="headset" />
              <Text>Jade</Text>
            </Button>
          </FooterTab>
        </Footer>
      );
    }
  }
));
```

Comment: May I know, how to target the element in which we want to display the screen on footer tab press?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a current index and bind the function to switch from a tab to another.
To do it use this :

```
import First from './First' 
import Second from './Second' 

class Updown extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.setState({currentIndex: 0}) // default screen index
   }

   switchScreen(index) {
      this.setState({currentIndex: index})
   }

   render() {
      let AppComponent = null;
//Here you can add as many tabs you need
      if (this.state.currentIndex == 0) {
         AppComponent = First
      } else {
         AppComponent = Second
      }

      return (
         <Container>
           <Header><Title> Header... </Title></Header>
           <Content> 
           {AppComponent}  // Load the component like this
          </Content>
           <Footer>
//HERE don't forget the bind function and pass the appropriate number
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen.bind(this,0) }> First </Button>
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen.bind(this,1) }> Second </Button>
           </Footer>
         </Container>
       )
   }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is not working at all for me. It throws an error `Objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @msqar its probably because it is not in string format. Convert it to string or parse it in a string using toString() function. Also, you have wrongly imported something or given as a un identified object

Answer (score 1):

I think that we can check some part of the @Hossein Mobasher code

```
import First from './Home' // your first screen
import Next from './Next' // your second screen

class Updown extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {index: 0} // default screen index
   }

   switchScreen(index) {
      this.setState({index: index})
   }

   render() {
      let AppComponent = null;

      if (this.state.index == 0) {
         AppComponent = First
      } else {
         AppComponent = Second
      }

      return (
         <Container>
           <Header><Title> Header... </Title></Header>
           <Content> 
            <AppComponent/> // you can write like this
           </Content>
           <Footer>
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen(0) }> First </Button>
               <Button onPress={() => this.switchScreen(1) }> Second </Button>
           </Footer>
         </Container>
       )
   }
}
```